# iTextSharp Acrofields in random order

Tags: .net, vb.net, itext

I'm currently developping a software that needs to use the iTextSharp library, unfortunatly as a student I can't afford to pay a commercial licence nor I can publish the source code (to comply with the licence) as I'm an intern, so I'm currently using iTextSharp 4.1.6 which is under the LGPL licence.

I'm trying to fill AcroFields in a pdf (see bellow) using SetField but the issue is when I'm trying to get all the Acrofields via AcroFields.Fields.Key they are stored in a random order see bellow.

This is the code that gets all the acrofields:

```
        Dim PdfReader As New PdfReader(ExistingFileStream)
        Dim Stamper As New PdfStamper(PdfReader, NewFileStream)
        Dim Form As AcroFields = Stamper.AcroFields
        Dim FieldKeys = Form.Fields.Keys
        For Each key As String In FieldKeys
            Form.SetField(key, valeurs.Item(I).ToString())
            I += 1
        Next
        Stamper.FormFlattening = True
        Stamper.Close()
        PdfReader.Close()
```

This is the original PDF which needs to be modified:

[image: the original PDF which needs to be modified]

This is what I get when reading AcroFields using the code above:

[image: what I get when reading AcroFields using the code above]

As you can see AcroFields are in a complete random order and I have no idea why it is. The thing is when you go down in each AcroField property there is an array called tabOrder which contains an integer, and this integer is correct ! "Nom" -> tabOrder(0) = 0, "Adresse" -> tabOrder(0) = 1 and so on.

In the Fields property "Adresse" should be the second one and "Nom" should be the first. They basically should be ordered by tabOrder.

Is this a known bug in the iTextSharp 4.1.6 ? I couldn't find anything about AcroFields being misordered like it does for me.

Thank you in advance.

Have a nice day.

Comment: If `valeurs` was a [Dictionary(Of String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the field key as the dictionary key then you could do something like `Form.SetField(key, valuers(key))`.

Comment: This is actually a good and fast workarround and I thank you for it.

Comment: AcroFields.Fields is a .NET IDictionary object. The order of its elements is undefined and can (theoretically) change from one implementation to the next.

Comment: Indeed I've tested the latest version for the matter and the issue doesn't occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring iText for a moment, imagine that I have a very simple database table full of people objects that have first names, last names, birthdays and user IDs. When you say "give me all of the people", what order should they be in? You personally might want things sorted by "last name, first name" but someone else might want them sorted by "birthday" and someone else might want them sorted by "ID". I would argue that none of these are "correct" or "better" and further argue that unless the API actually guaranteed a certain order or allowed me to specify something that it would totally be up to the consumer to sort things however they wanted to.

Back to iText, when you say "give me all the fields" iText does exactly that but there's no guarantee of a sort order. Some people will want all fields by name and some people will want all fields in visual left-to-right, top-to-bottom order. Personally I could care less about the tab order of a document when I'm processing it programmatically but that's just me. Also, the "tab order" that you mention isn't actually even in the PDF spec, that was just something that Adobe added to their product and both iText and Adobe make up on the fly!

Long story short, iText's order for fields might appear "random" to you but that also shouldn't matter because you should make no assumption about the order and you should sort things however you want.

Comment: I actually asked the question because in the latest version of iText, acrofiles are sorted the way you sorted them when creating the PDF with adobe's software. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Deodexed, I saw your note about that but I would still assume that there's no programmatic contract guaranteeing you that specific sort order going forward.

Comment: Does this apply to any programmation language ? Do we have to assume that when we retrieve data from any source it won't be ordered the way we want it to be ?

Comment: Unless the API contract tells you otherwise I'd say that you should make no assumption of order in any language, database, platform, etc. Something simple such as [`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) one might assume would come back alphabetical but the docs actually warn you that `The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required.`